# What does this property do in a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to research information about this property but  have not had luck finding a good explanation.

What does the property of a user control "Mode" do? or what is it used for?

```
 <uc1:MyWebControl runat="server" ID="uxMyWebControl" Mode="10" Visible="false" />
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Looks like it might be a custom property.  I don't remember Mode on a UserControl, do you have the source for MyWebControl?

Comment: Good catch, this is some existing code I am working on.. I thought it was a property. Thank you. Going to delete the question, or you want to answer it so I can give you the answer

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Good luck figuring out what it does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source code of MyWebControl, mode is not a property of a UserControl.